# App crash after '

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My application is crashing when a `'` appears  in the title of the `JSON` code i'm parsing.

This line is loading the title's:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:[item objectForKey:@"title"]];
```

**JSON:**

```
 NSString *jsonString = [NSString 
                            stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"**test.php"] 
                            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                            error:nil];
    // Create parser
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
    parser = nil;
    // Set tableData
    [self setTableData:[results objectForKey:@"items"]];
```

Crash:

```
tableData   NSArray *   0x00000001
```

> 2012-04-10 10:29:11.446 ****[21222:f803] -[NSNull isEqualToString:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146ace8 2012-04-10
>   10:29:11.447 ****[21222:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull
>   isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146ace8'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x13d4022 0x1565cd6 0x13d5cbd 0x133aed0 0x133acb2 0x15e0ff 0x2b10 0xb8c54 0xb93ce 0xa4cbd 0xb36f1 0x5cd21
>   0x13d5e42 0x1d8c679 0x1d96579 0x1d1b4f7 0x1d1d3f6 0x1db81ce 0x1db8003
>   0x13a8936 0x13a83d7 0x130b790 0x130ad84 0x130ac9b 0x12bd7d8 0x12bd88a
>   0x1e626 0x1ded 0x1d55) terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key part of that crash info is: `unrecognized selector sent to instance ... [NSNull isEqualToString:]`

It looks like your JSON contains `null` somewhere that you are expecting a string. Later on, probably inside of `setTableData:` you will be doing something like this:

```
NSString* whatever = [items objectForKey:@"whatever"];
if([whatever isEqualToString:@"hello"]){
    ...
}
```

And that will crash, because the `whatever` variable contains `NSNull`, not an `NSString` like you were expecting.

Comment: O haha sorry! `{"title":null,"description":""}` need to search my glasses again! Thanks haha!